# Looping through same array twice?

Tags: knockout.js

I have viewmodel like this,

```
        function viewModel() {
            this.Items = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

And I want to print something out like this,

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: {data: Items, as: 'item1' }">
        <span data-bind="text: item1"></span>
        <div data-bind="foreach: {data: Items, as: 'item2' }">
            <span data-bind="text: item2"></span>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

The above did not work, I get an error saying Items is not defined (at the line where I am trying to use it the second time).

So, I thought I will try this,

```
        function viewModel() {
            this.Items1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
            this.Items2 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

    <div data-bind="foreach: {data: Items1, as: 'item1' }">
        <span data-bind="text: item1"></span>
        <div data-bind="foreach: {data: Items2, as: 'item2' }">
            <span data-bind="text: item2"></span>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

I get a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What should the end result be?  The reason why Knockout doesn't know what `Items` is inside of your `foreach` is because it is iterating over the individual array and `Items` doesn't exist at that scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change context of your inner loop:
(example is based on your original intent)

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: Items, as: 'item1' }">
    <span data-bind="text: item1"></span>
    <div data-bind="foreach: {data: $parent.Items, as: 'item2' }">
        <span data-bind="text: item2"></span>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to accomplish is spitting out each value in the array, just change your markup to this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: Items, as: 'item1' }">
    <span data-bind="text: item1"></span>        
</div>
```

Here is the jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dymAQ/1/